# Laravelでログインユーザーがフォローしているユーザーの投稿を取得したい

Tags: laravel

### 実現したいこと

Laravelで、ブログ投稿アプリを製作しています。
そのアプリで、ログインユーザーがフォローしているユーザーの投稿を取得したいと思っております。（Twitterでいうタイムラインを実装するため。

### 試したこと

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function timeline()
    {
　　    $posts = Post::where('user_id', ココがわからない)->get();
    }
}
```

上記の第二引数に適切な値を記述すれば、取得できると考えているのですが、その値の検討がつきません。
第二引数にどのような値を記述すれば良いでしょうか？
また、別のアプローチなどがあればご教授していただけると幸いです。

### 補足情報

フォローに関するテーブルは以下になります。

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| follower_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| followee_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

リレーションの記述は以下になります。

```
User.php

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function followings(): BelongsToMany
{
　　return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follows', 'follower_id', 'followee_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function followers(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follows', 'followee_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

参考資料などが足りない場合などは、お申しつけください。

お手数おかけしますが、ご教授していただけると幸いです。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/283532

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/283667

Comment: ご掲示していただいたURL先でも質問をさせていただいたのですが、解決に到らなかったので、こちらのサイトで質問させていただきました。

Comment: 別の質問で追記されているところは同じような質問をされる可能性があるのできちんと条件として記述してください。例えばUserではなくPostでとってほしい等。さらにマルチポストをする場合は[マルチポストとはなんですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/)を一読しておくと良いでしょう

Comment: ありがとうございます。マルチポストの概念を存じ上げていなかったので、ご掲示していただいたリンクは大変助かりました。そして、条件をきちんと記述すること、心がけたいと思います。誠にありがとうございます。